# Timing Diagram in Microprocessor

Tags: microprocessor, timing

[image]

Though i know what is undergoing the microprocessor looking at the timing diagram, 
 what confused me is:  **What is the  amount of time period taken to complete the operation.**    What are the prerequisites to understand such timing related diagram. 
*Mainly Timing diagram of A15-A8 and AD7-AD0 seems confusing to me.*

Comment: I count three clocks by the time the operation has finished. T1 to output the MS address then two cycles in which the instruction comes back. During T3 the not-read goes high again so the next cycle can start at T4.

Comment: Why is it taking three clock pulse ??

Comment: Illustrating the steps as the homework or exam assignment requires would help you figure that out.  However, there isn't really enough information presented to know how long the operation takes overall - you only see the instruction fetch portion, so you don't really know when the result is being written back to the *internal* register file.  If you saw the start of a subsequent instruction fetch and knew the processor was not pipelined you could perhaps determine that.  A processor's instruction reference usually gives the number of clocks for an instruction in cases where it is variable.

Comment: Oh no, not that bloody 8085 again! Surya: you didn't even bother to mention which uP you are talking about :(

Comment: 8085 microprocessor

Answer (score 1):

In the first clock cycle, ALE and RD are high so that 16-bit Address can be placed on the address bus. Then ALE and RD go low so that in the second clock cycle, 8-bit opcode can be read and fetched from the memory, on to the data bus. In the third clock cycle, RD goes high. In the fourth clock cycle, processor does decoding of the instruction just fetched. Total no. of cycles = 4 for opcode fetch and decode operation in 8085.